# Why LESS doesn't override a property declared in two same selector?

Tags: less

Here is a code (test.less):

```
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Why after compiling to CSS I have this:

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

I thought that LESS would override *body* class and in CSS I'd have only one *body* class.

Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less does not work any different to CSS when it comes to that. What it does do is to rewrite nested blocks like

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
  h1 {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

into

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
body h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Hence in LESS, just like in CSS, the order in which you write your selectors does matter, and if conflicts can't be resolved by [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) (see [Nicolas Gallagher's post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-cascade-specificity-inheritance/) for a more readable explanation on how this works), as a general rule-of-thumb, the rule appearing last will be applied, thus overriding the earlier ones.

Comment: I already got answer from another question, but anyway, thank you!

Comment: What was the other answer @WasimAbu-Nassar?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo sorry for the my late answer. I've already forgot other answer, but it's pretty simple: code in the my question is correct and this is right way to extend CSS classes and variables, so if you want to customize class variable you should write new class and overwrite variable.